# IOS - UITableView get frozen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am currently having a hard time with a problem I have.

I created a View with 2 containers inside on is a UITableView and the other shows informations considering the first one selection.

Everything seems to work find except when I swipe for deleting (actually **I don't try to remove the row**, but just to reset the information contained in the object - a list of image - and refresh the view to show that the reset was done) on the left container.

At that time the process delete what has to be deleted and all (refresh also the UI) but sometimes after this event I can't select any object in my list any more, **like if the table was not User Interaction enabled any more** (Event aren't received any more I tried with break points). But the rest of the view is still working (I can still click on the right container's buttons etc). Moreover, if I click on my button to open the camera, when I get back the view is working perfectly again. Is there any ways that my refresh get stuck in some way ?

Xcode doesn't give me any stop so the program keeps on working.

I don't really know what code to show (I didn't put all the code but all I thought was important) :

```
@implementation PJTableViewController
{
    NSIndexPath *selectedRow;
    NSMutableArray *tableData;
}

@synthesize attachmentShow, attachments, listPJ;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(reloadTableView)
                                                 name:@"reloadLeftContainer"
                                               object:nil];

    selectedRow = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

    if( attachments != nil )
    {
        tableData = attachments.mutableCopy;
    }

    [listPJ setScrollEnabled:YES];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self selectCurrentRow];
}

// Selection
-(void) selectCurrentRow
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = selectedRow;
    [listPJ selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    [self tableView:listPJ didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}

//Reload
-(void) reloadTableView
{
    [listPJ performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
    [self selectCurrentRow];
}

-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    selectedRow = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    NSDictionary *dictionary = tableData[indexPath.section];
    Attachment *att = (Attachment*)[dictionary objectForKey:[dictionary allKeys][0]][indexPath.row];
    if( att )
        [attachmentShow setAttachment:att];
}

-(BOOL) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *dictionary = tableData[indexPath.section];
    Attachment *att = (Attachment*)[dictionary objectForKey:[dictionary allKeys][0]][indexPath.row];
    if( att.attachmentsPath.count == 0)
        return NO;
    return YES;
}

-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *dictionary = tableData[indexPath.section];
    Attachment *att = (Attachment*)[dictionary objectForKey:[dictionary allKeys][0]][indexPath.row];

    // Reset Attachment
    if( att.attachmentsPath.count > 0)
    {
        [att resetAttachment];
        [attachmentShow setAttachment:att];
        [self reloadTableView];
    }
}
```

`[att resetAttachment];` This line allow me to reset the attachment content.
`[attachmentShow setAttachment:att];` This line allow me to set the update the right container with the new informations.

Comment: In tableView:commitEditingStyle, don't use [self reloadTableView], use the appropriate method to delete a cell.

Comment: To expand on @Schemetrical's comment, use [deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:) on your tableView.

Comment: I edited my answer : I don't try to remove the row just to delete some informations in the linked object which is done perfectly and then refresh the view, my trouble comes from the refresh (that's my opinion)
The number of row Never changes but just the informations showed inside (mostly a pic and a number) changes

Comment: @CladClad use `-reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`. Never reload the entire `tableView` when you're updating specific things.

Comment: @Schemetrical you are completely right it seems it was just this. Thanks a lot for your answer make an answer so that I can validate it. Saved my days simple but I didn't know about this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`. Never reload the entire tableView when you're updating specific things.